How can create a range area chart using ApexChart same as figma
I'm using ApexCharts to create a range area chart in my project, but I'm struggling to replicate the exact design I have in my Figma file. Despite trying various customizations, I can't get it to look the same on my webpage.
I've already set up a basic range area chart in ApexCharts, but some specific design details (e.g., colors, line thickness, gradients, or other visual elements) are still off compared to the Figma mockup.
Could anyone provide guidance or examples on how to achieve a precise match with the Figma design? Any tips or tricks for customizing ApexCharts in detail would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!


my code
// components/ApexChart.js
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

// Dynamically import ApexCharts to prevent SSR issues
const ApexCharts = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });

const ApexChart = () => {
    const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState('1Y');
  const [chartTab, setChartTab] = useState('Histórico');

  const historicalData = {
    series: [
      {
        type: 'rangeArea',
        name: 'Team B Range',
        data: [
          { x: '24', y: [0, 0] },
          { x: '25', y: [10000, 20000] },
          { x: '26', y: [15000, 30000] },
          { x: '27', y: [20000, 35000] },
          { x: '28', y: [25000, 40000] },
          { x: '29', y: [30000, 45000] },
          { x: '30', y: [35000, 50000] },
          { x: '31', y: [40000, 55000] },
          { x: '32', y: [45000, 60000] },
          { x: '33', y: [50000, 65000] },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Team B Median',
        data: [
          { x: '24', y: 0 },
          { x: '25', y: 10000 },
          { x: '26', y: 20000 },
          { x: '27', y: 25000 },
          { x: '28', y: 30000 },
          { x: '29', y: 35000 },
          { x: '30', y: 40000 },
          { x: '31', y: 45000 },
          { x: '32', y: 50000 },
          { x: '33', y: 55000 },
        ],
      },
    ],
    options: {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'rangeArea',
        animations: {
          speed: 500,
        },
        toolbar: {
          show: false,
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      colors: ['#5951C3', '#5951C3'],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      fill: {
        opacity: [0.24, 1],
      },
      forecastDataPoints: {
        count: 0,
      },

      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth',
        width: [.5, 3],
      },
      legend: {
        show: false,
      },
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      markers: {
        hover: {
          sizeOffset: 5,
        },
      },

      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'En Dólares',
          style: {
            color: '#4B494E',
            fontSize: '16px',
            fontWeight: '400',
            fontFamily: "Figtree",
          },
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: (value) => `${(value / 1000).toLocaleString()}k`,
          style: {
            colors: ['#4B494E'],
            fontFamily: "Figtree",
            fontSize: '16.2px',
          },
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
        tickAmount: 10,
        axisBorder: {
          show: true,
          color: '#C6C6C5',
          offsetX: -48,
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        custom: function({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
          const date = w.globals.labels[dataPointIndex];
          const value = series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex];
          return `<div class="p-2.5 border border-[#4840BB] rounded-md bg-white shadow-md text-center">
                      <span class="text-xl text-center text-[#666666] font-plus-jakarta-sans font-normal">13 de enero, 2024</span><br/>
                      <span class="font-semibold text-center font-plus-jakarta-sans text-[#0D0D0D] text-[19px] leading-10">Retorno Total ${value}%</span>
                  </div>`;
        }
      },

    },
  };

  const projectionData = {
    series: [
      {
        type: 'rangeArea',
        name: 'Team B Range',
        data: [
          { x: '24', y: [0, 0] },
          { x: '25', y: [11000, 21000] },
          { x: '26', y: [16000, 31000] },
          { x: '27', y: [21000, 36000] },
          { x: '28', y: [26000, 41000] },
          { x: '29', y: [31000, 46000] },
          { x: '30', y: [36000, 51000] },
          { x: '31', y: [41000, 56000] },
          { x: '32', y: [46000, 61000] },
          { x: '33', y: [51000, 66000] },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Team B Median',
        data: [
          { x: '24', y: 0 },
          { x: '25', y: 16000 },
          { x: '26', y: 21000 },
          { x: '27', y: 26000 },
          { x: '28', y: 31000 },
          { x: '29', y: 36000 },
          { x: '30', y: 41000 },
          { x: '31', y: 46000 },
          { x: '32', y: 51000 },
          { x: '33', y: 56000 },
        ],
      },
    ],
    options: {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'rangeArea',
        animations: {
          speed: 500,
        },
        toolbar: {
          show: false,
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      colors: ['#615f79', '#5951C3'],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      fill: {
        opacity: [0.24, 1],
      },
      forecastDataPoints: {
        count: 0,
      },

      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth',
        width: [0, 2],
      },
      legend: {
        show: false,
      },
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      markers: {
        hover: {
          sizeOffset: 5,
        },
      },

      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'En Dólares',
          style: {
            color: '#4B494E',
            fontSize: '16px',
            fontWeight: '400',
            fontFamily: "Figtree",
          },
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: (value) => `${(value / 1000).toLocaleString()}k`,
          style: {
            colors: ['#4B494E'],
            fontFamily: "Figtree",
            fontSize: '16.2px',
          },
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
        tickAmount: 10,
        axisBorder: {
          show: true,
          color: '#C6C6C5',
          offsetX: -48,
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: false,
        },
      },

      tooltip: {
        followCursor: false,
        custom: function({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
          const date = w.globals.labels[dataPointIndex];
          const value = series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex];
          return `<div class="p-2.5 border border-[#4840BB] rounded-xl bg-white shadow-md">
                      <span class="text-sm">${date}</span><br/>
                      <span class="font-bold">Retorno Total ${value}%</span>
                  </div>`;
        }
      },
    },
  };

  const filterDataByYear = (data: ApexCharts.Series[], year: string) => {
    // Example logic to filter data based on the selected year
    const yearMapping = {
      '1Y': 1,
      '5Y': 5,
      '10Y': 10,
      '30Y': 30,
    };
    const yearsToShow = yearMapping[year];
    return data.map(series => ({
      ...series,
      data: series.data.slice(-yearsToShow), // Adjust this logic based on your data structure
    }));
  };

  try {
    const chartData = chartTab === 'Histórico' ? historicalData : projectionData;
    const filteredChartData = {
      ...chartData,
      series: filterDataByYear(chartData.series, selectedYear),
    };

    const yearOptions = ['1Y', '5Y', '10Y', '30Y'];
    return (
      <div className='max-w-[1250px] w-full mx-auto'>
         <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between items-start md:items-center gap-2 max-w-[1220px] w-full mx-auto'>
          <p className='text-16.88  font-plus-jakarta-sans font-normal text-[#222222]'>
            En la siguiente gráfica podremos observar cómo varía el rendimiento del fondo a través del tiempo:
          </p>
          <div className='flex justify-end w-full md:w-fit'>
            <div className='border-[#EEEEEE] bg-white border text-xs rounded-lg flex justify-between items-center px-[6px] py-[6px]'>
              <div
                className={`px-2 py-1 ${chartTab === 'Histórico' ? 'bg-[#CBC3FF] rounded-md' : ''} cursor-pointer`}
                onClick={() => setChartTab('Histórico')}
              >
                Histórico
              </div>
              <div
                className={`px-2 py-1 ${chartTab === 'Proyección' ? 'bg-[#CBC3FF] rounded-md' : ''} cursor-pointer`}
                onClick={() => setChartTab('Proyección')}
              >
                Proyección
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div className='flex justify-end pt-6'>
          <div className='flex items-center gap-x-3'>
            <div className='min-w-3 min-h-3 rounded-full'
              style={{ backgroundColor: chartTab === 'Histórico' ? '#5951C3' : '#888888' }}
            ></div>
            <p style={{fontFamily: "Calibri Light"}} className={`text-[#888888] text-xl`}>{chartTab}</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div className='-mt-9' id="chart">
          <ApexCharts
            options={filteredChartData.options}
            series={filteredChartData.series}
            type="rangeArea"
            height={400}
          />
        </div>
         <div className='flex justify-start mb-5 gap-5 charts-filter ml-7'>
          {yearOptions.map((label) => (
            <button
              key={label}
              onClick={() => setSelectedYear(label)}
              className={`px-2 py-1 text-sm rounded-2xl ${
                selectedYear === label ? 'bg-[#4b3a99] text-white' : 'bg-white text-[#707070]'
              } border border-[#707070]`}
            >
              {label}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div id="html-dist"></div>
      </div>
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error rendering ApexChart:", error);
    return <div>Error loading chart</div>;
  }
};

export default ApexChart;






I've set up a basic range area chart using ApexCharts, with custom colors and data configurations to try and match my Figma design. Specifically, I tried adjusting:
Color Schemes: I customized the color array and applied opacity levels to match the chart's color gradient.
Line and Area Styles: I adjusted the stroke properties (width, curve style) to replicate the line thickness and smoothness in Figma.
Tooltip and Axis Styles: I modified the tooltip and y-axis styling to align with the fonts, colors, and formats in the design.
Despite these efforts, my chart still doesn’t fully match the design. I’m expecting the chart to look visually identical to the Figma design, including gradient fills, line thickness, data point styling, and overall layout.
Would appreciate any insights on how to fine-tune ApexCharts settings to better match design specifics from Figma!
